Issue with Assuming service account role from the docker container running in EKS Pod
Currently we are running EKS cluster in AWS. We have created service account and annotated with IAM role.
Current scenario:

We are running a python script using Boto3 inside a docker container within a pod.
When I ran the same script within the pod, its working fine.
When I ran the same script within the docker, its failing to assume the service account tied to the pod, rather its assuming  node role.

Possible cause:

Since the script running inside the docker, its looking for a creds within the container and since its not able to found one, its falling back to node role

Expected output:

When we run the script from docker within a pod, it needs to assume service account role instead of Node role.

It would be great help, if some one could help here. I am sure people might encounter similar issues in the past. Looking forward to get a solution. Thanks in Advance.
